# How to verify JWT with UTC expiration time?

Tags: java, jwt, auth0

I have generated JWT using Auth0 JWT library,

```
                algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secretkey);                  
                token = JWT.create()
               .withIssuer(issuer)
               .withExpiresAt(UTCExpDate) //UTC now + 30 mins added
               .withIssuedAt(UTCDate)
               .sign(algorithm);
```

When I try to verify by following code,

```
             Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(secretkey);
             JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm)
            .withIssuer(issuer)
            .build();  
             DecodedJWT jwt = verifier.verify(token);
```

Getting following **`TokenExpiredException`** exception, because its verifying with current Time Zone that is +5.30 not UTC. Any right way to solve this issue ?

```
com.auth0.jwt.exceptions.TokenExpiredException: The Token has expired on Tue May 08 13:55:57 IST 2018.
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier.assertDateIsFuture(JWTVerifier.java:441)
    at com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier.assertValidDateClaim(JWTVerifier.java:432)
```

**Note:** Temporally I am solving this with adding **`.acceptExpiresAt(19800)`** while verifying. But I am looking for right solution for UTC verification.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt), you could provide a custom `Clock` implementation. Cast the `Verification` instance to a `BaseVerification` to gain visibility of the `verification.build()` method that accepts a custom `Clock`. For example:

```
BaseVerification verification = (BaseVerification) JWT.require(algorithm)
    .acceptLeeway(1)
    .acceptExpiresAt(5);
Clock clock = new CustomClock(); // Must implement Clock interface
JWTVerifier verifier = verification.build(clock);
```